# Intel MKL and Oracle R Distribution

Tags: r, oracle, intel, intel-mkl

I am trying to test the multi-threading advantages of using Oracle R Distribution. I have a workstation with a 12 core CPU and 32 GB of RAM available that I'd really like to exploit.

I've downloaded the latest Oracle R distribution and the 30 day trial of Intel MKL 11.1. I've specified my `PATH` per the Oracle documentation and in R studio when I run `Sys.BlasLapack()`, I am getting Intel Math Kernel Library (Intel MKL).

However my jobs aren't running any faster. Do I need to run one of the `.bat` files to actually compile and set parameters for the MKL? I don't have Visual Studio and I can't find anything on the web telling me how to do this. Any pointers? I am using Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Which Oracle R functions are you trying to use? The Oracle specific functions like `ore.odmGLM` may run faster, the standard R functions like `glm` will not run any differently. In fact they will be slow as they spool data from Oracle to your local R instance.

Comment: This might help you on the BLAS install: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#BLAS. I remember when I did this I had to recompile R to specify which BLAS to use.

Comment: I'm not running Oracle specific functions.  I'm running one of my regular jobs but using the Oracle distribution.  My understanding was that most mathematical computations would be faster.  How much faster would depend on how well the MKL could be leveraged.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer: Run the benchmark from [here](http://r.research.att.com/benchmarks/) under standard BLAS and Intel MKL to see if the MKL is working. MKL will only improve performance for some operations.**

To actually get the full power of the Oracle R implementation you would have to use the [embedded R functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40980_01/doc/doc.14/e39886/scripts.htm#CHDBHHJB). These are the ones that start with `ore`.

> In Oracle R Enterprise, embedded R execution is the ability to store R
>   scripts in Oracle Database and to invoke such scripts, which then
>   execute in one or more R engines that run in the database and that are
>   dynamically started and managed by the database.

We have tried out ORE in the office with Oracle running on an Exadata box; we began to see performance lift only when the datasets were *extremely large*.

If your goal is to take advantage of a more powerful BLAS you don't actually need Oracle R to do that. On a Unix distribution you can build open source R with using the `--with-blas` option (see [this link](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#BLAS)). I believe the same approach can be used for Windows although I've never compiled R from source with Windows.

Not all R functions run faster with the a different BLAS, in particular most modeling functions like `glm` don't use the BLAS. To check the performance of your system with different BLAS I have used [scripts from this site](http://r.research.att.com/benchmarks/). They will run much faster if the Intel MKL is being used. Maybe you should try one on your Oracle R distribution and compare with your open source install to confirm that ORE is using the Intel BLAS.

Overall I did not get much day to day performance improvement out of installing the Intel BLAS when I tried it. Revolution Analytics makes a big deal over how their non-free distribution of R leverages the Intel MKL. But they had to ***rewrite*** many R functions to take advantage of the increased speed.